# Python mysql get value from table before insert in the same table

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table with different type of article numbers:

```
Date -     Artsup - ArtTest - ArtCombo
-------------------------------
01-01-23  -   S1   -    T1    -  S1T1
01-01-23  -   S2   -    T2    -  S2T2
```

Now I want to insert a new record in the same table but first I want to check if I have a 'ArtCombo' available.

So now I first read the table like this:

```
cur.execute('SELECT ArtCombo from table1 where ArtTest = %s and Date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE()')
val = (varArtTest)

varArtCombo = value-from-select-query
```

In this way I get the ArtCombo value (if available). Now do a new insert using this ArtCombo value like this

```
sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (Date, ArtSup, ArtTest, ArtCombo) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
val = (datetime.now(tz=None), varArtSup, varArtTest, varArtCombo)
```

This works but wouldn't it be easier or faster to make this one single query? If so, how can that be achieved?

Comment: "*but first I want to check if I have a 'ArtCombo' available*" - Can you update your post with records that should not be added and records that should? Maybe you can do everything with one single `INSERT` statement.

Comment: No I can't because, in the end, this table has price-info per day. New Articles can occur which were not available the day before. Also the data is coming from different sources. Kind of complicated but i need to check before I can do the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

I've chosen a different approach to handle the issue. Transformed/catched my initial data in two pandas dataframes.
Did a merge on the frames and checked for the "left_only". This gives me the difference to work with:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, AllItemsFromDatase, indicator=True, how='outer')
newdf = df3[(df3._merge == "left_only")]
```

Now I have the items available in df1 and not available in the database, which was my goal.